# Sharing and syncing column data between several spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a private master spreadsheet that collects responses from a form. Then I have 9 shared spreadsheets that imports select data from the master sheet.  I need to sync column `A` 'Issue Addressed' between all spreadsheets so that any change in that column on the shared spreadsheets are reflected on the private spreadsheet.

I have tried importing the data from the private master spreadsheet, but I am unable to make changes to `A` 'Issue Addressed' column from the shared sheets.

Private Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_0WThnQa6G1A6ZvCegwa_eFRE4D4qUXgmA9TvqT4cCM/edit?usp=sharing

Shared Sheets: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M1AClhbjfzkjFyHXfJHRzCtkatvPqJyNtrumV0ufaPg/edit?usp=sharing

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("1_0WThnQa6G1A6ZvCegwa_eFRE4D4qUXgmA9TvqT4cCM", "response-master-list!A1:U1000"), "select * where Col8 = 'HMS'")
```

My goal is to have changes made to column `A`  'Issue Addressed' on the shared spreadsheet reflected on the private master spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your master spreadsheet run a script that looks at the column across the other sheets once a day and sync up. The non shared spreadsheets won't be able to touch your master.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried to import the shared columns to the private spreadsheet and check them there. But when i import the columns from the shared sheets the rows don't line up because they are being filtered.

Comment: Did you try writing into your script to save the current filters, clear all filters, copy the data, and then reapply the old filters?